# Javascript String between the brackets or not?

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, brackets

Why is the 1st parameter of the require function between the brackets ?
What is the difference if there is no brackets ?

```
require(['module'], function () {}, function (e) {
  // some code here
});
```

Comment: There is brackets because it's an array. Otherwise it'd be a string. You should probably learn more JavaScript before using require.

Comment: it's an array literal, in this case, an array of 1 string

Comment: I have not seen arrays been used in that function's 1st parameter. Normally there is only a string. So I can give an array of strings for the require. I understand now. Thanks.

Comment: Because you may want to depend on multiple modules for your app. Hence it must be an array here.

Comment: Yep. I understand this now loud and clear :D

Comment: To just pass a single string, its a sync way to get an already initialized module

Answer (score 4):

That indicates an array of 1 string.

With RequireJS/AMD modules, it's a way to declare what the inner function/module depends on. To just pass a single string, it's a sync way to get an already initialized module (meaning RequireJS or another loader has loaded and cached the module).

Comment: Allready initialized module... can you please explain a bit more ?